# .NET 6 obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, .net-6.0

I'm trying to obfuscate an .exe file obtained after compiling my .NET 6 project with the "Produce a single file" option, the problem is that no obfuscator works on it, I wanted to know if anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: "no obfuscator works on it" - which did you try?

Comment: @KlausGütter ConfuserEx, Beds Protector, Dotfuscator and Figma and 2 others friends try with their obfuscators and they say its a native file and they can't obfuscate it

Comment: `Produce a single file` the published .exe isn't your app. It's an archive contaning the app. Nothing to obfuscate there. To achive the objective you must change the building process.

Answer (score 3):

You have to obfuscate main application dll, which is located in the "obj\Release\net6.0-windows\win-x64" folder and copy obfuscated dll to the path.

Here is a working example using Obfuscar. These lines are located in the .csproj file.

```
    <Target Name="Obfuscation" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" Condition="'$(PublishProtocol)'!=''">
        <Exec Command="&quot;$(Obfuscar)&quot; obfuscar.xml" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(PublishProtocol)'!=''">
        <Exec Command="COPY &quot;C:\Users\Application\obj\Release\net6.0-windows\win-x64\Obfuscated\Application.dll&quot; &quot;C:\Users\Application\obj\Release\net6.0-windows\win-x64\Application.dll&quot;" />
    </Target>
```

After that, when you publish single file exe, your application code inside the archive will be obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish a .NET application as a single file, the actual code is located in the DLL file. The EXE file is just a launcher.

Returning to the obfuscation, the idea is to obfuscate the assembly right after it is placed to the intermediate directory by a compiler. E.g. if you use ArmDot you just write:

```xml
<Target Name="Protect" AfterTargets="AfterCompile" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Assemblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ArmDot.Engine.MSBuildTasks.ObfuscateTask
    Inputs="@(Assemblies)"
    ReferencePaths="@(_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')"
    SkipAlreadyObfuscatedAssemblies="true"
    />
</Target>
```

The same approach can be used with any obfuscator. The key thing is to use the following path: *$(ProjectDir)$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName)*.

After that, the obfuscated assembly (DLL) is published.