# How can I obfuscate a .NET 6 application?

Tags: .net-6.0, obfuscation

I tried to obfuscate a .NET 6 WPF Application with several Obfuscators. ArmDot, Babel, Skater...

Visual Studio creates WpfApp1.exe and WpfApp1.dll. All Obfuscators say, that the Exe is not a managed file. WpfApp1.dll is obfuscated (checked with dotPeek) but the exe wants to download ".net6 Destop" and does not work.

Comment: you need the correct version of .NET runtime installed where you want to deploy your app. It's a prerequisite for any .NET application.

Comment: related: [.NET 6 obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71005311)

Comment: @jps: the link is not the same question. My dll is obfuscated, but the exe does not run...

Comment: @Pac0: the application works before obfuscation and after obfuscation I need another runtime?

Comment: don't worry, I did not mark your question as a duplicate, just mentioned it as a related topic.